# Xamarin Forms Switch Controller width change

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can i change the switch width in xamarin forms switch?
[image]

tried with adding render class to android but couldn't found a way to do that.

[image]

---

### -------**this is the Render class in android**

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedSwitch), typeof(ExtendedSwitchRenderer))]

namespace Common.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class ExtendedSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        public ExtendedSwitchRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {

```
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var element = (ExtendedSwitch) e.NewElement;
            Control.TextOn = element.YesText ?? string.Empty;
            Control.TextOff = element.NoText ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control.SwitchMinWidth = 300;
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == ExtendedSwitch.YesTextProperty.PropertyName ||
            e.PropertyName == ExtendedSwitch.NoTextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var element = (ExtendedSwitch) Element;
            Control.TextOn = element.YesText ?? string.Empty;
            Control.TextOff = element.NoText ?? string.Empty;
        }
        Control.SwitchMinWidth = 300;
    }
}
```

### }

Comment: Please show your code not screenshots and include XAML or C# code where you put Switch control on the page/view as well.

Comment: attached 2nd screenshot is the android render class.